# It is possible to add a div with append? In this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrXvod)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>

 <div class="row" id="container-rec">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                   <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                     <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
                     <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                      <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
                      <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
             </div>
 </div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$('#add_new_rec').click(function (e) {
    // custom handling here
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.add').append('//my row');
});


$('.remove').click(function (e) {
     $(".remove").remove("//remove my last row")
});
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.row{
  display:none
}
```

How you can add a new line in the way I want it?
Basically I want a good solution to solve this problem ..

I do not want to

```
$('#mydiv').append('//some code HTML');
```

You can help me solve this problem?
Basically I want to add a line after each key click "add" and delete at least click on "remove"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you dont want to use append()?

Comment: ... I do not know another function we use something else?

Comment: @Marius what are trying to achieve is possible but why you are appending  that to buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that will

- add divs with inputs by cloning a hidden div
- change the associated IDs
- remove the last when remove is clicked

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").on("click",function() {
    var $container = $("#container-rec");
    var idx = $container.children().length; // how many children
    var $div = $("#orgDiv").clone(); // copy
    $div.prop("id","div"+idx);
    $div.find("label").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("for",$(this).next().prop("id")+idx); // change ID
    })  
    $div.find("input").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("id",$(this).prop("id")+idx); // change ID
    })  
    $container.append($div);
  });
  $("#remove").on("click",function() {  
    var $divs = $("#container-rec").find(".col-md-12");
    $divs.last().remove(); 
  });
});
```

```css
#orgDiv { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add">add</button>
<button type="button" id="remove">remove</button>

  <div id="orgDiv" class="col-md-12">
    <label for="clg_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="clg['name'][]" id="clg_name"><br/>
    <label for="clg_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="clg['email'][]" id="clg_email">
  </div>


<div class="row" id="container-rec">
</div>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104412/discussion-between-marius-and-mplungjan).